# A g++/c++ inconvenience

Tags: c++, ubuntu, g++

I am learning c++ and I am compiling lots of small programs without makefiles (using m-x compile) via g++.

When I want to compile according to c++14 I have to constantly add -std=c++14.

Is there a way to make g++ compile c++14 by default and avoid the extra typing?

Here is my current version:
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~16.04) 5.4.1 20160904.

Thank you.

Comment: use makefile's and then you just have to type 'make'

Comment: another option could be to define aliases for your commands to include correct -std flag

Comment: Or write a shell script, function or alias to do this.

Comment: I am quite a beginner and I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Starting in gcc 6.0  the default is `-std=gnu++14`

Comment: @NathanOliver So update gcc?

Comment: For the duration of your career you're going to have things you want to execute that require non-default arguments. Not all of these are going to conveniently go away with updates. Write a shell script, function, alias, makefile, etc. - whatever is appropriate for abstracting the "what" from the "how".

Comment: Right now I want to focus on c++ and I don't want to delve into gcc/makefiles/automake and I am looking for the "easy fix" for my problem, if it exists. Currently I prefer just typing a few extra characters than reading all the documentation, especially when dealing with small programs as I am.

Comment: @GManNickG Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Yup. In that case, write a tiny bash file consisting of a single line like `g++ -std=c++14 <blah blah blah>`, then to build run `bash that_file.sh`. This is not best practice for building or for bash scripts, but it's the shortest path to your goal.

Comment: You can modify your /.bash_profile and add `alias g++="g++ -std=c++14"` to it. However, you won't be able to compile using other standards such as c++11 anymore.

Comment: `alias` ?? just saying.

Comment: The problem with alias is that it will affect all invocations, probably not what you want. And a terminal-local alias is too scoped - it'll be lost when the session dies, and won't match across terminals. A project-level solution is appropriate.

Comment: Simpler solution:  create a text file, and capture every variant of compile commands you do.   NEXT time, 1) you open the compile-command-file (I use my editor), 2) find the line you want, 3) high light for copy, and 4) paste on the command line.  Ubuntu does not force you to use a mouse, and I have done this kind of effort without a mouse.  A lot depends on your editor, which is something you need to refine your abilities, anyway.  (emacs has macros ... very good for this effort)